# regular expression by question mark (Java)

Tags: java, regex, expression

I have collection `List<String> sentencesList = new ArrayList<String>` including sentencses from the text https://gist.github.com/c9afbb46abd50a28ef6e
I have to work with sentences by question mark only. So, I'm taking each element in my collection and I'm checking by regular expression

```
for(String sentence : sentencesList) {
            int count = 0;
            if(sentence.matches("([^.!?]*)\\?")) { ... }
}
```

In the text are nine sentences by question mark, but it's working only for one:

> He himself was a very old man with shaggy white hair which grew over
>   most of his face as well as on his head, and they liked him almost at
>   once; but on the first evening when he came out to meet them at the
>   front door he was so odd-looking that Lucy (who was the youngest) was
>   a little afraid of him, and Edmund (who was the next youngest) wanted
>   to laugh and had to keep on pretending he was blowing his nose to hide
>   it?

I suppose my problem is regular experession. Please, help! Thank's!

P.S. Regular expression is working only when after interrogative sentence are double line feed. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have a List of sentences, why not just do :

```
for(String sentence : sentencesList) {
    if (sentence.contains("?")){
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: `endsWith("?")` wouldn't work for a sentence like *"What's that noise?" said Lucy suddenly.*

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas true, but judging by OP regex I assume that for him/her sentence would be something like *What's that noise?*

Comment: Based on the regex, but if you look at github file they linked to it is clear that there are sentences like "What's that noise?".

Answer (score 0):

All the other sentences cannot match because they are inside other sentences, like: "What's that noise?" said Lucy suddenly. (it would only match one part of it, the sentence actually ends with a dot). And the first  sentence seems weird too: Once there were four children whose names were Peter Susan? Edmund and Lucy.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your regex this way and it seams to work fine, so it is probably your way of using it or your data are incorrect.

```
BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:\\testText.txt"));
String line = null;
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line = fr.readLine()) != null)
    lines.add(line);
// System.out.println(lines);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^.!?]*)\\?");
for (String tmp : lines) {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(tmp);
    while (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For question mark only:

```
String regex = "(?<=[?])\\s*";
```

Also you c an use `String regex = "(?<=[.!?])\\s*";` for `.` `!` and `?`

Comment: What do you think your regex is matching?

Comment: the simplest way to put the sign in square brackets `String regex = "[?]"` but if you need **e.g.** to split your strings by line without `extra spaces` at the start of the next line and exact contains the string with the sign delimiter - you should use `String regex = "(?<=[.!?])\\s*"`